# What is the current state of regulation regarding VTOL aircraft in the LSA category?

Tags: faa-regulations, light-sport-aircraft, vtol

With quite a few concept designs in progress, I am curious what the current FAA regulations are regarding vertical takeoff and landing vehicles in the light sport aircraft category.

Comment: Interesting question, do you have any links? The current definition of LSA excludes helicopters and powered-lift, so any VTOL design would have to avoid being classified as either of them.

Comment: Not sure that I have anything too reputable. I saw a sketchy manufacturer "concept" vehicle mention the two in the same sentence which is why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

The FAA term for VTOL [other than helicopters and lighter-than-air craft] is "Powered Lift". Also of note, gyroplanes by nature may be able to land vertical but cannot takeoff vertical so are not VTOL.

LSA excludes powered lift. Not much more to it, unless maybe it launches from a catapult and lands with a parachute.

title 14 CFR section 1.1 "General definitions":

> *Light-sport aircraft* means an aircraft, other than a helicopter or
>   powered-lift that, since its original certification, has continued to
>   meet the following:
>
> (1) A maximum takeoff weight of not more than—
>
> (i) 1,320 pounds (600 kilograms) for aircraft not intended for
>   operation on water; or
>
> (ii) 1,430 pounds (650 kilograms) for an aircraft intended for
>   operation on water.
>
> (2) A maximum airspeed in level flight with maximum continuous power
>   (VH) of not more than 120 knots CAS under standard atmospheric
>   conditions at sea level.
>
> (3) A maximum never-exceed speed (VNE) of not more than 120 knots CAS
>   for a glider.
>
> (4) A maximum stalling speed or minimum steady flight speed without
>   the use of lift-enhancing devices (VS1) of not more than 45 knots CAS
>   at the aircraft's maximum certificated takeoff weight and most
>   critical center of gravity.
>
> (5) A maximum seating capacity of no more than two persons, including
>   the pilot.
>
> (6) A single, reciprocating engine, if powered.
>
> (7) A fixed or ground-adjustable propeller if a powered aircraft other
>   than a powered glider.
>
> (8) A fixed or feathering propeller system if a powered glider.
>
> (9) A fixed-pitch, semi-rigid, teetering, two-blade rotor system, if a
>   gyroplane.
>
> (10) A nonpressurized cabin, if equipped with a cabin.
>
> (11) Fixed landing gear, except for an aircraft intended for operation
>   on water or a glider.
>
> (12) Fixed or retractable landing gear, or a hull, for an aircraft
>   intended for operation on water.
>
> (13) Fixed or retractable landing gear for a glider.

Comment: A link to the appropriate FAA document would greatly enhance this answer.

Comment: @AEhere There it is, title 14 section 1.1

Comment: Well, it looks like a (sufficiently-small, single-engine, no-more-than-two-seats, unpressurised) airship _could_ potentially meet all of those requirements...

Comment: A few gyros, fitted with collective-control rotors, can perform no-roll, vertical (or almost vertical) takeoffs. An example is the A&S 18A: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzAcNh56B5A